# Get shopify Metafields for products in one call

Tags: php, shopify

I have been trying to get metafields for over 100 products and that means I have to make separate 100 api calls for each product. If there is a way to grab all metafields for all products just in one xml file like the way variants are attached to products. So that with one api call, i grab all 100 products instead of making 100 separate api call for each product. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if it was mentioned in the API doc though. Nothing about

> Receive a list of all Metafields GET /admin/metafields.json?since_id=721389482

indicates it will only return shop metafields.

Answer (score 1):

We have had a lot of requests for getting metafields for multiple resources in the same request.  However, a lot of them could be handled by keeping the information at the applications side (e.g. in a database), along with the id of the resource.  This way the data is closer to where it is being used.

There are two very good reasons for using metafields

- Storing metadata to use from liquid templates
- Shared storage between applications

Metafields for liquid templates is great because the data is close to where it will be used for page rendering. This makes rendering fast and more customizable, because custom fields can be provided by apps and rendered in the storefront.

Shared storage between applications is another good reason to use metafields, but it doesn't appear to be a common reason metafields are used.  In this case the metafields API is currently lacking a way to access metafields on multiple resources at once.

Returning metadata along with products, however, is not a very good option. This is because other applications may store data in metafields that your application might not care about, so one application could end up slowing down a lot of other applications that don't even use metafields. This is why the metafields API has query parameters to restrict what metafields being retrieved, so metafields for other applications aren't returned unnecessarily.

Comment: My case is quite different, i don't have write permissions to metafields. I'm only reading those metafields like UPC, MPN, etc which I need along side the product. So i have to loop through about 100+ products to get those metafields, that is also slowing down my system. Also the metafields were added in the shopify storefront like product_type. So my thinking is if there is way to grab metafields related to each product in one api call. I don't care which application created it, i just want to read all metafields for all procuts and sort to pick those i want. Hope there could be a better way

Comment: It does sound like you have a valid use case, since these are shared metafield values.  I am sorry, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to do what you are looking for at the moment.

Comment: Why does the fact that grabbing 100+ products (1 API call) and then all their metafields (100+ API calls) take time matter to you? Are you  filling out some grid with that data for display? I have shops with thousands of products and each product has metafields. I use a background job to gather all that info together and then it emails it in a CSV. Works perfect.

Comment: Well, as you said, i'm displaying it in a grid but i think I will consider doing it via a background job. Are you doing it via PHP? Could share or explain further the calls you make in the background process. thanks

Comment: I know this answer is damn old, but the API hasn't changed since, so it's still relevant. "Returning metadata along with products, however, is not a very good option." What about a parameter `metafields: true`?

Comment: @Jerska Agreed. How has this not been asked for / demanded for by the Shopify user base in the 4 years since this question was asked?

Comment: @DylanSmith , @adaam I think this could actually be done while staying consistent with the webhooks behaviour: `metafields_namespaces: ['abc', 'def']`.

Comment: Can we get a response from the Shopify team member in reply to Jerska's comment on July 7th please? Not particularly satisfied with the answer (and with other responses on the Shopify support forum).

Comment: Bump. would love a flag to return metafields with a product